# How to read Hadoop files with Apache Beam?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-beam

I'm trying to read files with Apache Beam on a Hadoop server (not local). The problem is: How can I do that? I read something about Hadoop I/O Format with Beam:

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/hadoop/

I don't understand very well this part :

```
Configuration myHadoopConfiguration = new Configuration(false);
THIS --> // Set Hadoop InputFormat, key and value class in configuration <-- THIS
myHadoopConfiguration.setClass("mapreduce.job.inputformat.class", 
InputFormatClass,
InputFormat.class);
myHadoopConfiguration.setClass("key.class", InputFormatKeyClass, Object.class);
myHadoopConfiguration.setClass("value.class", InputFormatValueClass, Object.class);
```

How can I set this Format ? Do I need to create classes ? Because this code doesn't work if I c/p it. Thanks

Comment: InputFormat -- http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/api/index.html?org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/TextInputFormat.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard default InputFormat is [`TextInputFormat`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/TextInputFormat.html), which `extends FileInputFormat<LongWritable,Text>`

It reads `Long` values as byte offsets in the files. `import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable`

And `Text` values as singular lines. `import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text`

That code doesn't work because  `InputFormatClass`,  `InputFormatKeyClass` or `InputFormatValueClass` aren't actual variables